# C++ make new thread function with default parameter

Tags: c++, multithreading

Heyo everyone,
I'm currently playing around with threading in C++ and stumbled upon one quirk i couldn't quite find an answer to:

in my programm is a worker class which handles creating, and talking about a thread which does X.

```
worker::start(string filename){
   thread t(&worker::readfile,this,filename,10);
   t.detach();
}
worker::readfile(string filename, int LinesToRead = -1){
   stringstream ss = #open file and save as stringstream
   if(LinesToRead == -1){
      #read all lines from file
   else{
     #read "LinestoRead" lines from file
   }
   #does more with the stringstream to read it line by line, but not important here for the question.
}
```

this works fine, so does

```
thread t(&worker::readfile,this,filename,-1);
```

But why can i not call readfile as a thread with:

```
thread t(&worker::readfile,this, filename);
```

So if i leave the last variable "LinesToRead" blank it should default to -1, but i just get error messages when compiling.
It's not really an issue, but I'd like to know... euhm why this is? Just calling worker::readfile(filename) works, since "LinesToRead" defaults to -1, but calling it as a thread all variables seem to be required.

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, there's a difference between default parameters and overloads, even though they can achieve similar effects. For instance, you could have written this instead:

```
class worker {
 void readfile(string filename, int LinesToRead);
 void readfile(string filename) { readfile(filename, -1); }
 // ...
```

This overload achieves the same effect: you can call it with one or two arguments, and if you call it with one it behaves as if the second argument was -1. With the overload, `&worker::readfile` would be ambiguous because there are two functions named `readfile`. In your default argument case, there's only one function `readfile`. Therefore, `&worker::readfile` is not ambiguous, but its type is `void (worker::*)(string, int)`. The default argument is not part of the type.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the answer. Reading up on "default vs overloading", the latter seems to be a bit better in most cases. Ty for the lesson ^.^

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will put in default arguments for you whenever the function is called. But in

```
thread t(&worker::readfile, this, filename);
```

the function call is inside the standard library. The `thread` constructor gets a function pointer which can only be used with all arguments.

You could get around this using a lambda:

```
thread t([this, filename]() { readfile(filename); });
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer! Ye, the compiler just doesn't give the default value to the thread then. Ty :)